# Listing the contents of a directory in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

How do I get the contents of a directory in Fortran 95?

Comment: What do you mean "I have to pad it or otherwise it does not go through". What have you tried so far. Is it sufficient to print the contents of a directory to screen, or do you need to store the list of files in a variable?

Comment: @Chris : I was referring to the question itself, too short to be accepted by SO.

Answer (score 8):

shure if we have all the files in the 'inFiles' folder, we first find out how many are there and then we read their names into an array, check this out:

```
  real :: r
  integer :: i,reason,NstationFiles,iStation
  character(LEN=100), dimension(:), allocatable :: stationFileNames

  ! get the files
  call system('ls ./inFiles > fileContents.txt')
  open(31,FILE='fileContents.txt',action="read")
  !how many
  i = 0
  do
   read(31,FMT='(a)',iostat=reason) r
   if (reason/=0) EXIT
   i = i+1
  end do
  NstationFiles = i
  write(verb,'(a,I0)') "Number of station files: " , NstationFiles
  allocate(stationFileNames(NstationFiles))
  rewind(31)
  do i = 1,NstationFiles
   read(31,'(a)') stationFileNames(i)
```

!      write(verb,'(a)') trim(stationFileNames(i))
      end do
      close(31)

Answer (score 6):

To be pedantic, you don't. There's no intrinsic or such in Fortran 95 that helps you.

On a POSIX system and a recent Fortran compiler, you can use ISO_C_BINDING to create interfaces to the POSIX opendir() and readdir() functions (or readdir_r() if you need thread safety), which allow you to iterate over the directory entries.

Comment: Does this language allow to do anything useful except multiplying numbers ?

Comment: For comparison, can you point out where in the C or C++ standard one can find the functionality to list the contents of a directory?

Comment: one would expect that a standard library for such trivial operations is available out of the box for a language of such age.

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept of a directory in Fortran, as such. It reads files. (There are some processors that don't even have a concept of directory).

With that being said, the easiest way would be with SYSTEM. Depends on what you want with that after ...