# Printing Directory Listing in Fortran

Tags: directory, fortran, directory-listing

How can I print a list of all the files in a given directory using Fortran, limiting only to specific file types... For instance I only want to get the list of '.txt' files from a directory.

Files in directory:

- file1.txt
- another.dat
- test.mp3
- file2.txt
- file3.txt

something like

> WHILE (not_last_file  AND  filetype = '.txt' )
>
> {
>
> ```
> print FILENAME
> ```
>
> }

I would really appreciate your help,

Thanks

Comment: i dont know  why the down vote, its not a bad question just because it doesn't have a good standards compliant answer.  If you literally just want to print the list call system("ls *.txt"), where system is a common extension and obviously the call will depend on your os.

Answer (score 3):

In a few words, you can't. There's no intrinsic library for such operations in Fortran that helps you. How you approach this problem will also depend on the version of Fortran you are running (F77, F90, F95 etc.) which you do not state.

"On a POSIX system using recent Fortran compiler, you can use ISO_C_BINDING to create interfaces to the POSIX opendir() and readdir() functions (or readdir_r() if you need thread safety), which allow you to iterate over the directory entries."

See this post [Listing the contents of a directory in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892741/listing-the-contents-of-a-directory) or you could also look at [this overview from the gfortran documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranStandards#POSIX) useful.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "There is lots of information on performing this operation avalible with a simple Google." should never be an answer on SO imho

Comment: You are right. Let me update this answer - I think I provided enough information without that statement to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

MoonKnights's answer quotes janneb's answer in the linked question, which was had been closed because the actual question was just one unclear sentence. The quoted *"On a POSIX system using recent Fortran compiler, you can use ISO_C_BINDING to create interfaces to the POSIX `opendir()` and `readdir()`"* is completely true, but requires some work in the C language as the `dirent` structure is not easily and portably translatable to Fortran and it is better to work with just an opaque pointer there.

I use this:

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* open_dir(const char * const dir_name){
  DIR* d;
  d = opendir(".");
  return d;
}

void close_dir(DIR *d){
  if (d) closedir(d);
}

void next_file(DIR *d, char ch[256], int* len){
  do {
    struct dirent *dir = readdir(d);
    if (dir){
      if (dir->d_type == DT_REG)
      {
        strncpy(ch, dir->d_name, 256);
        size_t slen = strlen(dir->d_name);
        if (slen > 255) {
          *len = 255;
        } else { 
          *len = (int) slen;          
        }
      } else {
        *len = -1;
      }
    } else {
      *len = 0;
    }
  }
  while (*len<0);  
}
```

The code assumes that `NAME_MAX==255`. That will be true on most systems and avoids the need to get the value of that macro in Fortran. If that is a problem, you need to get the value of `NAME_MAX` to Fortran somehow or declare the header of `next file` in some different way.

The Fortran interfaces are then

```
  interface
    function open_dir(dir_name) result(res) bind(C, name="open_dir")
      use iso_c_binding
      type(c_ptr) :: res
      character(kind=c_char, len=1), intent(in) :: dir_name(*)
    end function
    
    subroutine close_dir(dir) bind(C, name="close_dir")
      use iso_c_binding
      type(c_ptr), value :: dir
    end subroutine
    
    subroutine next_file(dir, file_name, name_len) bind(C, name="next_file")
      use iso_c_binding
      type(c_ptr), value :: dir
      character(kind=c_char, len=1), intent(out) :: file_name(256)
      integer(c_int), intent(out) :: name_len
    end subroutine
  end interface
```

and you can loop over the files in the directory as

```
    type(c_ptr) :: dir_ptr = c_null_ptr
    integer(c_int) :: name_len
    character(256) :: file_name

    dir_ptr = open_dir("."//c_null_char)
    
    do
      call next_file(dir_ptr, file_name, name_len)

      print *, file_name(1:name_len)       
    end do
    
    call close_dir(dir_ptr);
```

The C code can be easily modified if you also need to list subdirectories (an `DT_DIR` branch after the `DT_REG` one or just use `||`).